# Adding up prices in foreach loop (PHP) - Not adding up

Tags: php, variables, math

... It's not as silly as it sounds...

I have the following code, which is used by my ajax table script to display database stuff on the page in a table.

```
foreach($ct->data as $key => $value){
    $ct->data[$key][2]='<a href="quantity.php?partno='.$ct->data[$key][0].'&description='.$ct->data[$key][1].'&quantity='.$ct->data[$key][2].'&order='.$o.'">'.$ct->data[$key][2].'</a>';
    $ct->data[$key][3]='<a href="quantity.php?partno='.$ct->data[$key][0].'&description='.$ct->data[$key][1].'&price='.$ct->data[$key][3].'&order='.$o.'">'.$ct->data[$key][3].'</a>';

    if($ct->data[$key][4] == "" || $ct->data[$key][4] == null)
        $ct->data[$key][4]='<a href="freight.php?partno='.$ct->data[$key][0].'&description='.$ct->data[$key][1].'&freight='.$ct->data[$key][4].'&order='.$o.'">Edit Charge.</a>';
    else
        $ct->data[$key][4]='<a href="freight.php?partno='.$ct->data[$key][0].'&description='.$ct->data[$key][1].'&freight='.$ct->data[$key][4].'&order='.$o.'">'.$ct->data[$key][4].'</a>';

    $Total =$Total+ $ct->data[$key][3];
    $freight =$freight+ $ct->data[$key][4];
}
```

And as you can see, in the `foreach` loop, I am trying to add up the contents of 2 columns.

The `$Total` column or, `$ct->data[$key][3]` lists the Prices for each row of products, and the `$freight` column does the same for each row of Freight charges.

And inside the `foreach` loop, I am trying to add together the total amount of prices, and Freight charges.

I'm not sure if I'm doing it the right way, because when I check the database, it just adds '0' (without the quotes). So it's not adding up!

For example, if there are a total of 3 rows in the table, and each product is 1 (dollar), it should add up to 3, right? And same goes for the `$freight` ones.

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: It looks like you're overwriting `$ct->data[$key][3]` with HTML

Comment: When I do a **print_r($ct->data[$key][3]); it shows the number without any html :S

Comment: $Total = $Total+ '<a href="...>' is very, very wrong for the math

Comment: Depends where you do the print - are you doing it before you overwrite it or after??

Comment: I'm doing the print after. Outside of the foreach loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting `data[$key][3]` equal to some HTML hyper link. Its not something that can be "totalled"

Comment: Ohhhhhhhhhh. Now I see. God I can be so thick sometimes.

Comment: YAAAAAAAY! I got it :P - Thank you heaps @Andy Paton. I'll accept when the timer runs out.

Answer (score 2):

Is line 3 not setting the value you're adding to $Total to a string?

```
$ct->data[$key][3]='<a href="quantity.php?partno='.$ct->data[$key][0].'&description='.$ct->data[$key][1].'&price='.$ct->data[$key][3].'&order='.$o.'">'.$ct->data[$key][3].'</a>';
```

and then

```
$Total =$Total+ $ct->data[$key][3];
```

If you remove the first one, the second might work better.